# php - execute several other php-scripts from php

Tags: php, invoke

From a PHP script, is it possible to execute another PHP-script with different GET variables?

I have a script that basically works like this (pseudo code):

```
// GENERATE STUFF
$ids = fetch_from_database();

foreach($ids as $id)
{
    $command = "wget http://someserver.com/php_script.php?id=$id > output_$id";
    exec($command);
}
```

For several reasons, I need to get rid of wget, and do this locally. What's the best way to achieve the above, without wget?

I've tried [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php), but it doesn't like that the same file is included twice or something. [Exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) can't take `$_GET` variables.

Preferably, "php_script" shouldn't have to be edited at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use curl https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: can you curl a local script, i.e. w/o using server address?

Answer (score 1):

I will copy & paste from my script where I am running some bots with it in my framework;

```
# Executing The Script
$data = array();
$data['start'] = 0;
$data['end'] = 20;

$url = SITE_ROOT.CRONS_DIR.$found->path."/".$found->name.".php";

$response = curlPost($url,$data,3,TRUE);

if ($response){
echo "<pre>";
echo htmlentities($response);
}
```

**curlPost function**

```
function curlPost($url, $postArray = NULL, $timeout=2, $errorReport=FALSE) {
    # PREPARE THE POST STRING
    if ($postArray != NULL) {
        $postString = '';
        foreach ($postArray as $key => $val) {
            $postString .= urlencode($key) . '=' . urlencode($val) . '&';
        }
        $postString = rtrim($postString, '&');
    }

    # PREPARE THE CURL CALL
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL,            $url         );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HEADER,         FALSE        );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POST,           TRUE         );
    ($postArray != NULL) ? curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     $postString ) : '';
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,        $timeout     );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE         );

    # EXECUTE THE CURL CALL
    $htm = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_errno($curl);
    $inf = curl_getinfo($curl);

    # ON FAILURE
    if (!$htm) {
        # PROCESS ERRORS HERE
        if ($errorReport) {
            echo "CURL FAIL: {$url} TIMEOUT={$timeout}, CURL_ERRNO={$err}";
            echo "<pre>\n";
            var_dump($inf);
            echo "</pre>\n";
            createLog("CURL FAIL: {$url} TIMEOUT={$timeout}, CURL_ERRNO={$err}");
        }
        curl_close($curl);
        return FALSE;
    }

    # ON SUCCESS
    curl_close($curl);
    return $htm;
 }
```

This code allows me to execute the script with CURL, and move on to running another bot.

You can loop the first code (above the function) so you could run multiple (& different) php scripts without waiting for response (or you could wait).

I hope this helps.